# IntelliJ Dependencies - Difference between Specifications und Implementations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies

When starting a new JavaEE Project in IntelliJ you are prompted to include either Implementations or Specifications in your project. Can anyone explain whats the difference here, lets say in context to Hibernate/JPA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you develop with a full featured Java/Jakarta EE application server, like GlassFish you only need to add dependency on specification JARs and the application server will provide their implementations.

Different application servers provide different set of supported Java EE standards. For instance, GlassFish provides almost everything while Tomcat provides servlet-api and websocket-api and that's it.

If you choose more lightweight server, like Tomcat, to develop and deploy you should choose Java EE libraries (implementations) because Tomcat will not provide you JPA or JMS library.

Full list of Jakarta specifications (APIs): https://jakarta.ee/specifications/